# What does "type" mean in this text?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm reading this book, and there is a love scene in which I don't understand the usage of the word "type".
Here I quote a large chunk containing the word in question:

> The whole affair was the precise opposite of what I figured it would
>   be: slow and patient and quiet and neither particularly painful nor
>   particularly ecstatic. There were a lot of condomy problems that I did
>   not get a particularly good look at. No headboards were broken. No
>   screaming. Honestly, it was probably the longest time we’d ever spent
>   together without talking.
>   Only one thing followed **type**:
>   Afterward, when I had my face resting against  Augustus’s chest,
>   listening to his heart pound, Augustus said, “Hazel Grace, I literally
>   cannot keep my eyes open.”
>   “Misuse of literality,” I said.
>   “No,”
>   he said. “So. Tired.”
>   His face turned away from me, my ear pressed
>   to his chest, listening to his lungs settle into the rhythm of sleep.
>   After a while, I got up, dressed, found the Hotel Filosoof stationery,
>   and wrote him a love letter: ...

(from *The Fault in Our Stars*, by John Green)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is [to] **follow type**.

It means to run true to form, to occur in a predictable way.

It is uncommon nowadays, perhaps considered a little rarefied. I haven't found it in any dictionary other than [All Dictionary](http://www.all-dictionary.com/word/follow%20form), where it seems to be used incidentally; perhaps 'follow form' was intended.

The associated sense of 'type' *is* given by dictionaries, eg [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/type):

> **type** b. An example or a model having the ideal features of a group or class; an embodiment: "He was the perfect type of a military dandy"
>   (Joyce Cary).

OALD, I think (but it keeps misdirecting me to 'type I': but ODO/OALD is usually what the 'Google Dictionary' quotes) has the definition and synonyms

> a person or thing exemplifying the ideal or defining characteristics
>   of something.
>
> "she characterized his witty sayings as the type of modern wisdom"
>
> synonyms: epitome, quintessence, essence, perfect example, archetype,
>   model, pattern, paradigm, exemplar, embodiment, personification,
>   avatar; prototype

So 'follow type' would be 'conform to the expected pattern'; it is idiomatic in that padding words are not included (contrast *'follow pattern').

Again, rare nowadays.

Comment: Thank you. Having searched for it in Google Books in different date ranges, I agree with you that it is rare. Perhaps never been so common, especially in this idiomatic form.